# Python aiohttp pars

Tags: python, python-requests, python-asyncio, aiohttp

I want to parse a lot of links using iohttp, but it doesn't work in real time, parse each one in turn. How do I make it so that I parse each one continuously?

```
import aiohttp
import asyncio


list = ['value1', 'value2', 'value3', ..... 'value6000']

async def main():
    async with aiohttp.ClientSession() as session:
        while True:
            for i in list:
                async with session.get(f"https://example.com/{i}") as response:
                    print(response.json())

loop = asyncio.get_event_loop()
loop.run_until_complete(main())
```

Comment: It's not what your issue is, but don't overwrite builtins such as `list` unless you know what your doing. It will cause issues down the road.

Answer (score 0):

If you are looking for processing a list, you should check `asyncio.gather()`.

Example of usage:

```
import asyncio
import os

from aiohttp import ClientSession, ClientError, TCPConnector
from asyncio import TimeoutError, gather



async def asyncmain(your_list):

    async with ClientSession(
        connector=TCPConnector(limit_per_host=SESSION_LIMIT_PER_HOST)
    ) as session:
        tasks = (your_async_call(session, title) for title in your_list)

        return await gather(*tasks)
```